# How to extract tables with data from .sql dumps using Spark?

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark

I have around four *.sql self-contained dumps ( about 20GB each)  which I need to convert to datasets in Apache Spark.

I have tried installing and making a local database using InnoDB and importing the dump but that seems too slow ( spent around 10 hours with that )

I directly read the file into spark using

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

var sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("sparkSession").getOrCreate()
var myQueryFile = sc.textFile("C:/Users/some_db.sql")

//Convert this to indexed dataframe so you can parse multiple line create / data statements. 
//This will also show you the structure of the sql dump for your usecase.

var myQueryFileDF = myQueryFile.toDF.withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id()).withColumnRenamed("value","text") 


// Identify all tables and data in the sql dump along with their indexes

var tableStructures = myQueryFileDF.filter(col("text").contains("CREATE TABLE"))
var tableStructureEnds = myQueryFileDF.filter(col("text").contains(") ENGINE"))

println(" If there is a count mismatch between these values choose different substring "+ tableStructures.count()+ " " + tableStructureEnds.count())

var tableData = myQueryFileDF.filter(col("text").contains("INSERT INTO "))
```

The problem is that the dump contains multiple tables as well each of which needs to become a dataset. For which I need to understand if we can do it for even one table. Is there any .sql parser written for scala spark ?

Is there a faster way of going about it? Can I read it directly into hive from .sql self-contained file?

UPDATE 1: I am writing the parser for this based on Input given by Ajay

UPDATE 2: Changing everything to dataset based code to use SQL parser as suggested

Comment: If the sql contains multiple tables, how would you envision this becoming 1 dataframe / dataset? Otherwise you should write your own data source format https://hackernoon.com/extending-our-spark-sql-query-engine-5f4a088de986

Comment: edited . I wanted to do it for one table to dataframe . edited question to better reflect this . thanks

Comment: What is the separator between entries (table definitions and rows) in the sql dump?

Comment: You have a create table statement  followed by a bunch of insert into table statements . So given the dump The code i wrote can extract all tables and enumerate them into a dataset

Comment: I am stuck at the point where  all create statements are extracted into and RDDArray[String] Which need to be parsed in order to create empty dataset structures for multiple tables . How would one do that using the parser ?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any .sql parser written for scala spark ?

Yes, there is one and you seem to be using it already. That's Spark SQL itself! Surprised?

The SQL parser interface (`ParserInterface`) can create relational entities from the textual representation of a SQL statement. That's *almost* your case, isn't it?

Please note that `ParserInterface` deals with a single SQL statement at a time so you'd have to *somehow* parse the entire dumps and find the table definitions and rows.

The `ParserInterface` is available as `sqlParser` of a `SessionState`.

```
scala> :type spark
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

scala> :type spark.sessionState.sqlParser
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserInterface
```

Spark SQL comes with several methods that offer an entry point to the interface, e.g. `SparkSession.sql`, `Dataset.selectExpr` or simply `expr` standard function. You may also use the SQL parser directly.

---

**shameless plug** You may want to read about [ParserInterface — SQL Parser Contract](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-ParserInterface.html) in the Mastering Spark SQL book.

Comment: Hi , Jacek thank you for the reference. These seem to be individual commands to deal with sql statements . There is no process specified for mysql dumps. I dont mind constructing it here for others to use if you can guide me .

Comment: That's correct. `ParserInterface` deals with a single SQL statement at a time.

Comment: This only helps with statements that are compatible with HIVE SQL otherwise you get "no viable alternative at input"  errors . I am facing that actively for MYSQL query parsers .

Comment: Well, for such errors, you'd have to find out an alternative solution (even doing the SQL parsing yourself). Spark SQL at least could help a bit so you don't have to parse everything (just "edge" cases).

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse it by yourself. It requires following steps -

1. Create a class for each table.
2. Load files using textFile.
3. Filter out all the statements other than insert statements.
4. Then split the RDD using filter into multiple RDDs based on the table name present in insert statement.
5. For each RDD, use map to parse values present in insert statement and create object.
6. Now convert RDDs to datasets.

Comment: Cool . I thought this was an old problem so there would someone who wrote a script to share . :)

Comment: Becauase the tables are large ..each table has multiple INSERT statements .