# Spark based analysis of MSSQL imported file

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark, sql-server-2008, pyspark

We have a small size Spark cluster version 3.x. We have to analyze a database dump file obtained from MS SQL Exporting. Its format is .sql that contains first schema of each table and then insert statements. The schema is completely in MS SQL format.

I have searched a lot and found some connectors to MS SQL server but could not found any stuff related to the analysis of MSSQL dump file. What could be the possible way for this Purpose? I am using PySPark API.

Some references that I found in this regard:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/spark-mssql-connector?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I think you are mixing up the term "dump file" which generally means a [memory dump from SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/tools/use-sqldumper-generate-dump-file), not a set of DML/DDL. This may generate some odd responses to your question. Next, explain exactly what output you want when Spark "analyzes" this file.

Comment: Let me to updated my question

Comment: The links you posted have nothing to do with "dumps", nor do they explain anything. SQL Server doesn't have `dumps`. That's a term used by databases that either don't have real backups or charge for them, to refer to scripting the contents instead of providing a real backup file. They often refer to real backups as `physical` and scripts as `logical` backups. SQL Server backups aren't data, they're copies of the actual binary data pages.

Comment: Scripting the contents is a **horrible** way of transferring data too. It's no better than using a CSV (both are text after all), takes far more space than a CSV and you actually have to parse the SQL statements to find out columns and values.

Comment: PS there's no `MS SQL Exporting` either. The `Export Data` menu option in the SSMS management tool exports data in multiple formats - CSV, Excel, directly to other databases, probably even HDFS, Avro and ORC. The wizard generates an SSIS package which [*does* support HDFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/hdfs-file-destination?view=sql-server-ver15). It *doesn't* generate SQL scripts, precisely because these are just language scripts, not data. It makes no sense to emit an `INSERT` line where only half of it is data

Comment: Why don't you just read the data from the database? That's what they're for. If you really want to read the SQL scripts, you need a SQL parser. Luckily [Spark SQL already does that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52108677/how-to-extract-tables-with-data-from-sql-dumps-using-spark), but this wastes a **lot** of time and CPU generating scripts then parsing them back, to end up with the same data plus the metadata.

Comment: So you have a file (which you call a dump file) which consists of DDL and inserts and you want to analyse with spark. It would be much easier if the data was provided to you as parquet. Failing that, some kind of delimtied text file. What options do you have with regards to data extracts? and the overriding question is: why even use spark if this is actually relational data in the first place? Is there a python library that you think you need to use?

Comment: Theretically you could also create a table in spark by running the SQL that you have using the SQL kernel , probably with some changes, since it supports create table and insert